# The most of the images don’t appear, although URLs are correct

Tags: images, uploads

I don't understand. The most images on my website [Eslovaquia.sk](http://www.eslovaquia.sk/) don't appear despite the fact that all are in a valid folder. E.g. logo. There is broken-image-icon instead the logo in the header. However, link displays a right image, when I right-click on that icon, copy an URL address and paste it into the new window. It happens after moving wordpress from subfolder into the root (eslovaquia.sk/wp > eslovaquia.sk)

Comment: server is returning 403 forbidden errors, maybe some htaccess rule or other server configuration is causing this.

Comment: Really? Do you think a link to an image? E.g. http://www.eslovaquia.sk/wp-content/themes/tma/images/bg/logo_slovaquia.gif ? I do see it.